# subplots having 2 x-axis using plotly

Tags: plotly

I am currently trying to plot using graph object plotly. However I want the plot to show both the top and bottom xaxis. I am able to get the two axis in one of the top subplot but could not get the axis in rest of the plots.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

label_par = [r'$x^2$ \n [cm]', r'$x^3$ \n [cm]']

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, vertical_spacing=0.01,
                    specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}], [{"secondary_y": True}]])
# panel(a)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16], 
showlegend=False, text=["(a)"], textposition='top left'), row=1, col=1, secondary_y=False)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16], 
showlegend=False), row=1, col=1, secondary_y=True)
# panel (b)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 8, 27, 64], 
showlegend=False,text=["(a)"], textposition='top left'), row=2, col=1, secondary_y=False)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 8, 27, 64], 
showlegend=False), row=2, col=1, secondary_y=True)
fig.update_layout(plot_bgcolor='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)')
fig.update_yaxes(linecolor='black', secondary_y=False, showgrid=False)
fig.update_yaxes(linecolor='black', secondary_y=True, showgrid=False)
fig.update_yaxes(minor_ticks="inside")
fig.update_xaxes(ticks="inside")
fig['layout']['yaxis1']['title'] = label_par[0]
fig['layout']['yaxis3']['title'] = label_par[1]
fig.update_layout(xaxis3={'anchor': 'y1', 'overlaying': 'x', 'side': 'top'},
                  xaxis4={'anchor': 'y3', 'overlaying': 'x2', 'side': 'top'})
fig.data[0].update(xaxis='x3')
fig.data[1].update(xaxis='x4')
fig.update_xaxes(linecolor='black', showticklabels=False, showgrid=False)
fig.update_xaxes(showticklabels=True, row=2, col=1)
fig.write_image("/home/dhanya/Desktop/compiled.pdf", width=600, height=600)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtVY0.png)

Comment: Can you provide sample data and current output figures? Data should be pasted in text.

Comment: Hi I have edited the comment to include figure and data

Answer (score 0):

I too have a hard time trying to handle the second axis in plolty. In this case, yours also moves the way you have already set it up. You can see the details of multiple xy axes in fig.layout, so you need to rely on that to specify them individually.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

label_par = [r'$x^2$ \n [cm]', r'$x^3$ \n [cm]']

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, vertical_spacing=0.000,
                    specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}], [{"secondary_y": True}]])
# panel(a)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                         y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16],
                         showlegend=False,
                         text=["(a)"],
                         textposition='top left'),
              row=1, col=1, secondary_y=False)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                         y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16],
                         showlegend=False),
              row=1, col=1, secondary_y=True)
# panel (b)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                         y=[0, 1, 8, 27, 64],
                         showlegend=False,text=["(a)"],
                         textposition='top left'),
              row=2, col=1, secondary_y=False)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                         y=[0, 1, 8, 27, 64],
                         showlegend=False),
              row=2, col=1, secondary_y=True)

fig.update_layout(height=450,
                  #template='plotly',
                  plot_bgcolor="white",
                  yaxis1_title_text=label_par[0],
                  yaxis3_title_text=label_par[1])

fig.update_yaxes(showline=True, linecolor='black', showgrid=False)
fig.update_xaxes(showline=True, linecolor='black', mirror=True, showgrid=False)
fig.update_xaxes(tickvals=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], ticks="inside", minor_ticks="inside")

fig.update_layout(xaxis={'anchor': 'y', 'overlaying': 'x2', 'side': 'top'},
                  xaxis2={'anchor': 'y3', 'overlaying': 'x', 'side': 'bottom'},
                 )

#fig.write_image("/home/dhanya/Desktop/compiled.pdf", width=600, height=600)
fig.show()
```

[image]